# On click event on two buttons, get value of non-pressed button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have two buttons that I assign an event to. I know how to capture the value on the clicked button, but not on the non-clicked button. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
var $b1 = $('<input/>', { 'type': 'button', 'value': '0' });
var $b2 = $('<input/>', { 'type': 'button', 'value': '1' });
var $bm = $b1.add($b2);  
$myDiv.append($bm);      
$bm.on('click', function() {         
    var clicked = $(this).val();
    var not_clicked = ???
```

Comment: Could you loop through them and do a `if(!$(this).is(":checked"))`?

Comment: @SJGJ sorry I misread the question.  Had check boxes in my head for some reason.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out the current clicked input

```
$bm.on('click', function() {         
var clicked = $(this).val();
var not_clicked = $bm.not(this).val();  
// select both buttons.. filter out current clicked with not().. get val()
```